# Ubuntu LVM on LUKS UEFI

Tags: ubuntu, lvm, hook, initramfs-tools

I want to install Ubuntu on LVM on LUKS in UEFI mode. An UEFI partition, another encrypted partition for `/boot` and again an encrypted partition for system.

**My question is:**
How can I add hooks to `initramfs`?
It's so easy on Arch Linux by editing `mkinitcpio`.
But I don't know how to do that in Ubuntu.